# Match a string variable to the location in data file(specified column) so I can use all values in that row VB?

Tags: vb.net, match

The row that the string matches to I want to assign variables to the rest of the values in that row for every column. 
This is what I tried for finding the match which I think is wrong:

```
Dim intIndex As Integer
For Each Str As String In strColumn(1)
If Str.Contains(strID) Then
intIndex = Str.IndexOf(strID, 0)
End If
Next
```

Even once I find the matching row number how do I tell each variable what row and column to assign itself to?

sample of a row and each column is separated by a ",":  1234567,03/02/2013,7,2,B,L,ST
and there are unlimited rows of these

Comment: Sorry, but your question is really difficult to understand. What is row (DataRow, DataGridRow or??) What is strColumn? Please add more code and explain better the context of your question

Comment: It looks like you may be working with a CSV file? Can you post some sample input so we can see what you are working with?

Comment: I'm trying to tell a variable what row and column to assign itself to base on what row the known variable strID matches to.  strColumn is the column I am looking for a matching string for strID.

Comment: In other words, if the ID in the current row matches the ID you're looking for, you want to assign the remaining comma separated values to individual variables?  Can you have more than one matching row in the file?

Comment: exactly Tim, you explained it better than myself.  It can only have one matching row in the file.

Comment: I don't have time to give some sample code, but the easiest thing to do would be to read each line, split on the `,`, and then check the ID column - if it matches, populate your variables with the remaining elements of the array resulting from the split.  If I get time (and someone else doesn't do it first), I'll post an example later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go - assuming you have an array of strings (rows) already (perhaps from a file with `ReadAllLines`), something like this should get you going in the right direction:

```
Dim rowFound As Boolean = False
Dim rowNumber As Integer = 0
Dim columns As String()
Dim col1 As String = ""
Dim col2 As String = ""
Dim col3 As String = ""
Dim col4 As String = ""
Dim col5 As String = ""
Dim col6 As String = ""
Dim col7 As String = ""

Do While Not rowFound And rowNumber < rowArray.Length
   columns = rowArray(rowNumber).Split(New Char() {","c)
   If columns(0) = strID Then
       rowFound = True
       col1 = colunns(0)
       col2 = columns(1)
       col3 = columns(2)
       col4 = columns(3)
       col5 = columns(4)
       col6 = columns(5)
       col7 = columns(6)
   Else
       rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
   End If
Loop
```

Some things to note:

First, I haven't tested this so there might be some syntactic errors (I do a lot more C# than VB.NET).

Secondly, I used a While Loop so that you don't waste time checking every line if you find the one you're looking for early on.  The While Loop will exit if the flag rowFound is set to true or the rowNumber count exceeds or equals the length of the array (assuming 0-based index array).

Inside the While Loop, it splits each row and checks the ID.  If there's a match, it populates the variables with the column values and sets the rowFound flag to True, ending the loop.  If there isn't a match, it increments the rowNumber variable and looks at the next row (if there is one - if there isn't, the While Loop exits).

You may have to do some casting if you want to store the values in types other than String (your second column looks to be a DateTime).

Anyway, this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I changed it a little but I was able to get my program up and running.  Thanks a lot for helping me!!

Comment: You're welcome - I glad you got it working. :)